# How to auto activate jquery script

Tags: jquery, responsive

I am a real jquery newbee and have found this script - and it works great but only when I touch the screen (mobile) ...

What I am searching for is a way to activate the script automatically ... Can anyone help me?

```
<script>
    //  changing the order of the sidebar so it goes after the content for   mobile versions

    jQuery(window).resize(function(){

        if ( jQuery(window).width() < 480 )
        {
            jQuery('.mid_grid_right').insertBefore('.mid_grid_left');
        }

        if ( jQuery(window).width() > 480 )
        {
            jQuery('.mid_grid_left').insertBefore('.mid_grid_right');
        }

        jQuery(window).height(); // New height
        jQuery(window).width(); // New width
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The callback function is not called automatically when your DOM is ready, so you should do:

```
<script> 
   function resizeFn(){
      if ( jQuery(window).width() < 480 ) {
        jQuery('.mid_grid_right').insertBefore('.mid_grid_left'); 
      } 
      if ( jQuery(window).width() > 480 ) { 
         jQuery('.mid_grid_left').insertBefore('.mid_grid_right'); 
      }
      jQuery(window).height(); // New height
      jQuery(window).width(); // New width
   }

   jQuery(window).resize( resizeFn );
   jQuery(document).ready( resizeFn) ;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the resizing logic into it's own function and then wireup an event to call the same function :

```
<script> 
    // When your page is ready (and jQuery is loaded), call your function
    $(function(){         
        resize();
    });
    // When the window is resized, call your function
    $(window).resize(function(){
        resize();
    });
    // Define your function
    function resize(){
        if ($(window).width() < 480 ) {
            $('.mid_grid_right').insertBefore('.mid_grid_left'); 
        } 
        if ($(window).width() > 480){ 
            $('.mid_grid_left').insertBefore('.mid_grid_right'); 
        } 
        $(window).height(); 
        $(window).width(); 
    }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is within a listener for the `resize` event. To make the same code run on pageload, simply add a listener for document.ready and pass a reference to the same function.

```
function gripChange(){
    if ( jQuery(window).width() < 480 )
    {
        jQuery('.mid_grid_right').insertBefore('.mid_grid_left');
    }
    if ( jQuery(window).width() > 480 )
    {
        jQuery('.mid_grid_left').insertBefore('.mid_grid_right');
    }
    jQuery(window).height(); // New height
    jQuery(window).width(); // New width
}

jQuery(window).resize(gripChange);
jQuery(document).ready(gripChange);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the whole block with jQuery ready. The DOM is not ready the way you implemented it and the browser does not know yet what "window" even stands for.

Additionally, don't repeat jQuery(window) again and again for a faster response.

```
<script>
    //  changing the order of the sidebar so it goes after the content for mobile versions
    jQuery(document).ready(
        var $window = jQuery(window);
        $window.resize(function(){

            if ( $window.width() < 480 )
            {
                jQuery('.mid_grid_right').insertBefore('.mid_grid_left');
            }
            // if ( jQuery(window).width() > 480 )
            else
            {
                jQuery('.mid_grid_left').insertBefore('.mid_grid_right');
            }

            $window.height(); // New height
            $window.width(); // New width
        });
    });
</script>
```